# How to align all characters of an captcha image to a line in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, captcha, python-tesseract

I am new to image processing. I need to pass an image to pytesseract to get the content of an image. Before that I need to preprocess image in a way where all the characters of an image is align to bottom of the image whereas pytesseract easily detect those characters.

**I am with opencv-python,4.5.5 and Python 3.8**

The images I am working on look like-

[image: 1]

***Update:***
I have tried with the code mentioned as below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(r"dialated.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
ret, img = cv2.threshold(img, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

Contours = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
Contours = sorted(Contours, key=lambda x : cv2.boundingRect(x)[0])
#Contours.sort(key=lambda x : cv2.boundingRect(x)[0]) #throws exception so commented out and used the above line instead.

newImg = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
bb = cv2.boundingRect(Contours[0])
newY = (bb[1] + bb[3])
for Contour in Contours:
    [x, y, w, h] = cv2.boundingRect(Contour)

    newImg[newY-h+1:newY+1, x:x+w] = img[y:y+h, x:x+w].copy()

cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.imshow("newImg", newImg)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But I am facing error as below:

```
File "E:\Zone8\Shariful\Zone8\PrepaidMeters\captchaTest\removeBG\aligningContours.py", line 17, in <module>
  newImg[newY-h+1:newY+1, x:x+w] = img[y:y+h, x:x+w].copy()

builtins.ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (168,245) into shape (167,245)
```

Answer (score 5):

The approach is simple, just read the image, get the contour for each number, sort the contour from left to right, create a new image, and copy-paste the numbers from the old image on the new image keeping the same the y-coordinate of the bottom left corner. Here's the code for the same below:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("CapthaImg.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
ret, img = cv2.threshold(img, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

Contours = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
Contours.sort(key=lambda x : cv2.boundingRect(x)[0])

newImg = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
bb = cv2.boundingRect(Contours[0])
newY = (bb[1] + bb[3])
for Contour in Contours:
    [x, y, w, h] = cv2.boundingRect(Contour)

    newImg[newY-h+1:newY+1, x:x+w] = img[y:y+h, x:x+w].copy()

cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.imshow("newImg", newImg)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Below are the input and output images:
Note that I have reversed the input image for contour detection.

Input Image

[image: input image]

Output Image

[image: output image]

Comment: I am getting error `builtins.AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'sort'` at line `Contours.sort(key=lambda x : cv2.boundingRect(x)[0])`

Comment: I guess you forgot `[-2]` at the end of the above line. This error is coming because Contours in your code is a tuple of contours and hierarchy.

Comment: I have indexed `[-2]` but what I did is I loaded png image.

Comment: I am not able to understand your issue, but you can try this in place of the sort line:
`Contours = sorted(Contours, key=lambda x : cv2.boundingRect(x)[0])`

Comment: I am with `opencv-python,4.5.5 and Python 3.8`

Comment: Now another error `  newImg[newY-h+1:newY+1, x:x+w] = img[y:y+h, x:x+w].copy()

builtins.ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (168,245) into shape (167,245)`

Comment: I think the problem is `Contours` has only one element in my case!!